# C# find all devops build definitions with DEPECRATED tasks

Tags: c#, azure-devops-rest-api

We updated from `TFS Version 2017` to `Azure Devops`. We see now that we have some build steps they are marked with `DEPRECATED`. The idea is now that we write a `C#` console application which generate a list with all `DEPRECATED` build steps. Finally we don't find a property in `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi.BuildDefinitionStep` which we can check is this step marked as `DEPRECATED` or not.

We tried this with the code below written in `C#`. Variable `step` has not a property which we can check is the step deprecated or not.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //For TFS :
    var tfsUrl = "http://[serername]:[port]/[tfs]/[name]";
    var buildClient = new BuildHttpClient(new Uri(tfsUrl), new VssAadCredential());

    var definitions = buildClient.GetFullDefinitionsAsync(project: "Projects");

    foreach (var definition in definitions.Result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("\n {0} - {1}:", definition.Id, definition.Name));
        foreach(var phase in ((Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi.DesignerProcess)definition.Process).Phases)
        {
            foreach(var step in phase.Steps)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{step.DisplayName} has no property to check is this step marked as deprecated or not.");
            }
        }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you try to achieve is not available in Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client NuGet package.

But you can request your DevOps server with an HttpClient to "_apis/distributedTask/tasks/{id}" endpoint. You would get back a JSON object in the response where the deprecated field is available if your task definition is depracated. Finally you can serialize your JSON into a dynamic object to check the deprecated property.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //For TFS :
    var tfsUrl = "http://[serername]:[port]/[tfs]/[name]";
    var buildClient = new BuildHttpClient(new Uri(tfsUrl), new VssAadCredential());

    var definitions = buildClient.GetFullDefinitionsAsync(project: "Projects");

    foreach (var definition in definitions.Result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Check {definition.Id} - {definition.Name}...");
        foreach (var phase in ((Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi.DesignerProcess)definition.Process).Phases)
        {
            foreach (var step in phase.Steps)
            {
                var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
                handler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                var client = new HttpClient(handler);
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(tfsUrl);
                var response = client.GetAsync($"_apis/distributedTask/tasks/{step.TaskDefinition.Id}").Result;

                var jsonResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                dynamic d = JObject.Parse(jsonResponse);
                if (d.Result != null && d.value[0].deprecated == true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"'{step.DisplayName}' is deprecated");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue..");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. It works now perfect.